# Select records going into expiry

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table:

```
ProductID
Datecreated
Serialnumber
```

The products have an expiry of 2years after they are created. I'm trying to produce a Select to show the products that are due to expire within the next 6months.

What I've done so far gets the date 6months from now but doesn't take into account the 2 years.

```
Select *
From product
Where datecreated (day, 182, getdate())
```

I think I'm way off the mark, any guidance on the type of function I need to use would be appreciated!

Comment: did you write anything so far? you can get help tuning your code but please don't ask us to write it for you.

Comment: Sorry I've updated, I'm not the best with SQL, confused on the type of function I need to use

Comment: I have added a test case as an answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [interval literals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i38598) to do the math:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  datecreated + INTERVAL '2' YEAR <= SYSDATE + INTERVAL '6' MONTH
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> create table prod_expiry as select * from(
  2  WITH DATA AS(
  3  SELECT 1 ProductID, add_months(SYSDATE, -20) Datecreated, 10 Serialnumber FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 2 ProductID, add_months(SYSDATE, -22) Datecreated, 10 Serialnumber FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 3 ProductID, add_months(SYSDATE, -16) Datecreated, 10 Serialnumber FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 4 ProductID, add_months(SYSDATE, -10) Datecreated, 10 Serialnumber FROM dual UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 5 ProductID, add_months(SYSDATE, -12) Datecreated, 10 Serialnumber FROM dual)
  8  SELECT *
  9  FROM DATA)
 10  /

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM prod_expiry
  2  /

 PRODUCTID DATECREAT SERIALNUMBER
---------- --------- ------------
         1 16-FEB-13           10
         2 16-DEC-12           10
         3 16-JUN-13           10
         4 16-DEC-13           10
         5 16-OCT-13           10

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM prod_expiry
  2  WHERE add_months(Datecreated, 18) >= SYSDATE
  3  /

 PRODUCTID DATECREAT SERIALNUMBER
---------- --------- ------------
         3 16-JUN-13           10
         4 16-DEC-13           10
         5 16-OCT-13           10

SQL>
```

So, the query now picks only those records which are yet to expire in next 6 months or less than 6 months.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not know basic algebra. So, in order to take benefit of a potential index on `datecreated`, you should write your query by isolating `datecreated` on one side of the relational operator `<=`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  datecreated <= SYSDATE + INTERVAL '6' MONTH - INTERVAL '2' YEAR
--     ^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
--     this is as                       this is a
--       column                         constant
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/345bf/4 (click on *View Execution Plan* for both queries)